# Separate the files based on a string in the data

Tags: bash, awk, rename

Hello I had already asked this question but due to in sufficient information it is termed invalid. Let me frame my question again.

I have many files starting with ECEPYO in Ravi directory.

Based on the string "BOFA2016ECG" if the string is present in the file i should rename the file and move it into new directory teja.

If the string is absent in the file i need to move it to Test folder.

I am using the following code

```
INBOUND=/mnt/data/Ravi/ECEPYO.*
for i in `ls $INBOUND` ; 
do

awk '/BOFA2016ECG/{file="/mnt/data/teja/BOFA" ++c ".dat"} {print > file}'  $INBOUND

done
rm $INBOUND
```

This is working fine when the string is available; but when the string is not available i am getting the following error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/mnt/data/Ravi/ECEPYO.266031 FNR=1) fatal:       expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

I need some assistance to develop the code when the string is not available and moving the file to different folder.

The below code is able to solve the issue;

```
INBOUND=/mnt/GXSdata/Ravi/ECEPYO.*
for i in `ls $INBOUND` ; 
do
 SEARCHSTRING=`grep BOFA2016ECG $INBOUND | cut -c217-227 `

 if [ "$SEARCHSTRING" = "BOFA2016ECG" ];
 then

  awk '/BOFA2016ECG/{file="/mnt/data/teja/BOFA" ++c ".dat"} {print > file}'   $INBOUND
  else
     cp $INBOUND /mnt/data/test
  fi;    
done
rm $INBOUND
```

But it is working only for single file; when there are multiple files in the folder the renaming file is not working what should be used to modify multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid parsing the output of `ls`, instead use:

```
for i in /mnt/GXSdata/Ravi/ECEPYO.*
```

Where you do your `grep`, you should use `i` rather than `$INBOUND` if you mean to look in one file at a time, and you could consider using the newer `$(...)` rather than backticks:

```
SEARCHSTRING=$(grep BOFA2016ECG "$i")
```

Rather than using `cut`, you can probably use `grep -o` to extract just the word, or you can pattern-match in `bash` using the `=~` operator.